# MVC as best practice for professional level programming?

Tags: php, model-view-controller

Long time lurker, first time poster...

I'm now at the point where I'd almost call myself a professional grade PHP programmer and have a lot of code I re-use in various projects. Also, a lot of Open Source packages I've worked with use the MVC model and as a result I've done a lot of research recently into how it all works so I can better edit them as required.

At this point, I'm considering taking a bare-bones MVC framework (from a tutorial) and extending it as required for my forthcoming programming jobs.

My question is whether the MVC model with pretty much all application logic separated from the presentation layer is considered best practice over a well structured OOP website with coding on the page as necessary e.g setting function variables.

Or will I run into issues when I want coding flexibility e.g.

- using something like PHPthumb for a  gallery where I want different output
  sizes on different pages and currently set parameters in the head
  of the page
- a contact form with x fields and a feedback form with y fields - will this require 2 differrent models rather than a generic form class again with some parameters set in the head of the page
- some pages requiring ob_start() and ob_flush() but not others?

Please don't tell me not to build my own framework - I'd rather know how each little bit works than use a slab of code I know nothing about - I'm really interested in the opinion of people who have gone this route and build sites every day. What are the real pros and cons of this over plain (but well structured) OOP and bunch of pages to a site as opposed to 1 index.php page and separate files.

Cheers,
Niggles

Comment: `I'd rather know how each little bit works than use a slab of code I know nothing about` -- sure, you know nothing about the code **at first** but since php code is plain readable, it'd be your fault if you don't want to study the code.

Comment: If you're really interested in what "people who have gone this route" have to say, you shouldn't lead off with "please don't tell me to build my own framework."  Because that IS the best answer.

Comment: Besides, using a well respected framework is a great way to grow your understanding of implementing the MVC pattern, which would help you build your own should you still find the available solutions lacking.

Comment: I'm definitely in the "learn one (or a few) but build your own as well" camp.  There's just no reasonable way to understand why wheels are round until you try to make an octagonal one.  That said, built it up as needed. Don't spend time designing features that don't have any applicability and end up being wasted.

Comment: I wrote a blog post on creating your own MVC from scratch in PHP - https://chaitya62.github.io/2018/04/29/Writing-your-own-MVC-from-Scratch-in-PHP.html Hope this helps

Answer (score 15):

I know you say you don't want this advice, but don't write your own.  The first thing I've done at every single job I've ever worked at is picked up some existing code or framework, often commercial but highly modified, and begun maintaining it.  You'll seldom get the option to write your own, and doing so is a bad idea.  It's hard, expensive, and somebody else has already written a better MVC PHP framework than you're likely to write.

There are literally dozes of [mature PHP frameworks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_web_frameworks#PHP), most of which have been around for over a decade. Choose one of them. It doesn't matter which one - they're all maintained by a dozen people at least as smart as you who've been writing MVC frameworks a lot longer, and have spent months or years refining their frameworks and listening to user input.

All that said, if you want to write your own on your own time, as a hobby, so you're not wasting your boss's money, then by all means.  There's a huge variety of interpretations of MVC.  Some frameworks view views as basically templates.  I personally think you can throw as much raw PHP in there as you'd like, so long as it's purpose is display, and you do the usual smart things like distilling out shared code into functions.  Some frameworks have virtually no business logic in the models (where it belongs IMO) but have very heavy controllers.  The best thing you can do is try other frameworks and see how they work, and which you like best, and decide what you'd like to see changed.  Then, set out to change it in your own.

You say you're almost ready to consider yourself a professional?  The hardest lesson I had to learn was that professionals don't write their own low-level libraries.  They don't reinvent the wheel on the company buck.  They use off-the-shelf components and get the job done today, rather than a month from now.  You don't want to use a slab of unfamiliar code?  That's the biggest part of your life to come as a programmer - get used to it.

Comment: "I know you say you don't want this advice, but don't write your own."
Fair call in all that you said-but I guess my plan isn't to go and build some gigantic beast that would take 12 months to write. I'm doing a lot of similar jobs at the moment - custom CMS systems, minisites with multiple galleries & forms and next month I have a CRM with time management facilities. I wanted to start consolidating my work into something re-usable even if it's piece by piece.

"professionals don't write their own low-level libraries." Agreed - I use several 3rd party classes if they exist and do the job :-)

Comment: @meagar: Regarding your last paragraph, if everyone though the same way you do there wouldn't be any **professional PHP frameworks**, and there are plenty of them! I'm not saying he should roll his own on his company hours but total discouragement is not advisable in my opinion.

Comment: @AlixAxel I know this is almost five years old, but I'll follow up anyways. The important thing is that almost no existing "professional" PHP framework was written solely for the sake of writing a professional PHP framework. That's a great way of producing an ugly framework that nobody wants to use. Good frameworks get distilled out of *real world* applications, where somebody saw a real problem and came up with a solution. Then they saw the reusable bits, or perhaps they thought they had a particularly elegant architecture, and that formed the basis of their framework.

Comment: This is perhaps the *real* reason I'm trying to get across for why you shouldn't build your own framework. Yes, they're a great learning too, but *good* existing frameworks have proved themselves capable of hosting many types of application at many scales; they're battle-tested and hardened, and the *bad* bugs have been shaken out for you. Of course everybody should feel free to experiment with their own ideas for a framework, but the thrust of this question is becoming a *professional*, and professionals do *not* solve *already solved* problems by writing frameworks.

Answer (score 3):

Writing your own framework is great for your own edification and for truly understanding the language.

Personally I find its as time consuming using a third party framework as it is to write your own. Yet I have total control of my own code, not something you can claim with any third party framework.

I also think many MVC frameworks are very resource intensive. For high volume sites you need to be prepared to throw hardware at them to get them to run nicely. For low volume sites (the majority) the rapid development of a third party MVC framework is a huge bonus.

So in my opinion if you have the time, roll your own and be proud of it. Just make sure you learn from others especially where security is concerned.

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on what are you project requirements are and how you design your application objects. MVC do not force you to use an specific class or view design, It will only provide you with an architecture that will help you isolate the business logic from the presentation and the data layer making you application more scalable and easy to test.

In MVC you are not tied to one view per controller you can use as many views as you want per controller since every exposed method can call a view itself and control how it looks and behave based on the business logic you define. That said you can have 2 methods to return a full size image and a thumbnail without having to create two pages. You can set everything on the view from the controller, header meta-data, scripts, links, theme, content, etc...

In regard to the models, it again depends on your project requirements but definitely, in any case, if you have several pages with different purposes and they require to modify different data sources there should be a model for each one of them and what you can do after is to create a class that encapsulates the form functionality by calling the model for getting the fields to create form, get and save the data. This is just an idea you can do it in a lot of different ways, that is the beauty of OOP.

In the end it is not a matter of comparing a well structured OOP site against an OOP MVC site, It is more an analysis of the time and effort you spend working on building a site architecture that can succeed in isolating concerns at the same time it still readable and scalable while it meets your project requirements.

If you want to get more ideas about design patterns you can use google MVP design pattern and/or MVVM design pattern.

Answer (score 1):

I have written my own framework.  It does not take time to create the architecture and raw code.  It's great if someone writes there own framework.  But If documentation is not proper than definitely pain in asses.  Completely depends upon yourself. I have written mine as well.  It took almost 7 days to make framework QA ready :). but the main issue is to get satisfied by the piece of code you write in your framework.  You would always like to improvise your framework and wanted it to be best ever.  BLAH! BLAH! If you wish to write your own and you are confident enough for sustenance.  GO for it.

Answer (score 0):

Any MVC -- homegrown or not -- will allow you flexibility and re-usable code.

ob_start() / ob_* calls are no problem, they go in your model and called from your template, e.g.:

```
Hello <?php echo $this->getFormattedName(); ?>
```

where your model is

```
function getFormattedName() {
    ob_start();
    echo '<a href="/profile/' . $this->getName() . '">' . $this->getName() . '</a>';
    $return = ob_end_clean();
    return $return;
}
```

For your form scenario, you would probably want an abstract form class that defines how a field is made and its validation, then each specific form would extend your abstract.

You may want to consider using something like Zend Framework -- while it's an MVC library in its own right, you can pull in single components super easily (for example, you can pull in Zend_Form and Zend_Mail for your contact and feedback forms & validation and use your own models for everything else).  This would also give you the extra benefit of having a fallback when/if the time comes when your homebrew MVC framework starts to outgrow its original design.  Or, at the very least, speed up your development time so that you're not held up for days because you suddenly realize you need an e-mail model.

Comment: This use of output buffering seems... excessive.  What's wrong with string concatination?

Comment: Nothing's wrong with concatenation.  Just an example, since the OP specifically asked about using `ob_start()` etc. :)

Comment: This is exactly wrong. Your models should never output HTML, that's what the view is for. The *entire point* of MVC is decoupling your business objects from your display code. This is also exactly how *not* to use output buffering. Shoe-horning it in because it was referenced in the question doesn't make it any more valid.

Comment: Touché.  You are technically more correct than I.  I would argue that my answer wasn't so much wrong as improper; I think it did validly answer the question.  I'm not trying to teach the OP how to code.  The line gets blurred sometimes, for example in Zend_Form the Zend_Form_Element class builds the structure of the form.  While it doesn't straight up echo HTML, it gets pretty close.